# When using inheritance with beans, why does request scope break?

Tags: jsp, javabeans

Here's the scenario:

In the JSP file, I have:

where, this bean is a subclass Bean like so:

```
public class NonpUserBean extends NonpRegBean {
```

This scenario causes issues any attempt at RequestDispathcer.forward to go to an "error" page.

However,

```
<jsp:useBean id="nonpRegBean" class="com.manavmisra.nonprofit.NonpRegBean" 
   scope="request"/>
```

works fine.

In other words, when using the "subclass" Bean, request scope is crashing out. However, request scope, in the exact same scenario works if I use the "superclass" Bean.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

If the `nonpRegBean` is actually an `NonpUserBean` object, it cannot be instantiated from the `com.manavmisra.nonprofit.NonpRegBean` class . `NonpRegBean` can be a reference type specified by the `type` attribute , but it cannot be the `class` attribute . I assume that the bean are defined as per the specs.

The `class` attribute specifies the actual class of the bean instance.The `type` attribute specifies the Java type by which the instance is handled, which may be a superclass of the bean's class or an interface implemented by it.If there is not already an attribute of the specified id in the specified scope then `useBean` attempts to create one. It can only do
that if it knows what class to instantiate. If there is already a matching attribute then `useBean` attempts to use it; it will be cast to the type specified by `type` if that is provided, or to the type specified by `class` otherwise.

Check if any attribute named `nonpRegBean` exists in request scope.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. However, I don't guess I understand. nonpRegBean does work with the request scope. However, nonpUserBean, which extends nonpRegBean does not.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, upon closer look at another related JSP, I was "creating" a new request bean with the same "id" as from the nonpRegBean class, instead of the nonpUserBean class. This appears to be similar to what you are referring to, and once I changed this around, the stuff works. Thanks again.